# stuck starting substrate local host has moved

Tags: polkadot-js

Im working on the substrate for the first time.
https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/build-local-blockchain/

stuck right here:
Open http://localhost:8000/ in a browser to view the front-end template.

File has moved. Any clue where it is or the specs i need to continue step 3 on the front end template. Also, does this mean my chain is working?

Answer (score 1):

The docs are wrong. It's running on port 8080

Answer (score 1):

After run the command `yarn start` in the **substrate-front-end-template** you will see in the command line how to view it in the browser:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view substrate-front-end-template in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:8000/substrate-front-end-template
  On Your Network:  http://your-ip:8000/substrate-front-end-template
```

Open one of this urls in your browser to see it.

If you don't have the substrate-node-template running you will see something like this:
[image]

If this happens come back to the tutorial to check how to start the local node:
`./target/release/node-template --dev`